# AppleScript: on error (try) line number

Tags: applescript, try-catch, onerror

Is it possible to get the line number, where the script threw an error?

Example:

```
try
    set a to "abc" + "123"
 on error line number num
    display dialog "Error on line number " & num
end try
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

i don't think so try statements look like this

```
try
    set a to "abc" + "123"
 on error errMsg
    display dialog "ERROR: " & errMsg
end try
```

but you could look at [script debugger](http://www.latenightsw.com/sd4/run_debug.html) which will show you what line your error occurred on

another alternative is to get [textmate](http://macromates.com/) which goes for $52 when it errors it gives you the line number and is also useful for writing code in many languages

Comment: $199 for an apple script debugger, no thanks. +1 for pointing it out, though.

Comment: You can now download and use if free for 20 days, and after that some features are disabled but you can still use the "lite" version.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the on error syntax include the error number also (but no line number):

```
try
    set a to "abc" + "123"
on error errorMessage number errorNumber
    log ("errorMessage: " & errorMessage & ", errorNumber: " & errorNumber)
end try
```

You can use semaphores to mark your progress:

```
try
    ... your code here ...

    set lineNumber to "17"

    ... more code here

    set lineNumber to "18"

    ... more code here

on error errorMessage number errorNumber
    log ("(line #" & lineNumber & ") errorMessage: " & errorMessage & ", errorNumber: " & errorNumber)
end try
```

And I'll 2nd mcgrailm's recommendation for [Script Debugger](http://www.latenightsw.com/sd4/run_debug.html)!

Comment: it might be silly question, but where can we see that errormessage and error number log

Comment: Script Editor & Script Debugger both have console logs where that output will appear. When running stand-along scripts the logs go to the system console.

Answer (score 2):

Satimage's [Smile](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/downloads/index.html) is of great help when it comes to debugging an applescript.

And it's free.
Plus it's French (hehe).

Definitely a great tool !

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here, but in respect to Script Debugger, here is a perhaps useful response from Mark Alldritt:

> Yes, turn on Break On Exceptions. This cause the debugger to break at the point where an exception is thrown.  The debugger also shows the sate of all known variable at the time the exception is thrown.  You can then step into the 'on error' block.

Cheers
-Mark

On 2013-01-24, at 8:43 AM, Dan wrote:

When a script throws an error in a Try block, is there any reasonable way to display the line where the error occurred?